# Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, google-chrome-extensions, remote-access, chrome-remote-desktop

I have been successfully able to use Chrome Remote Desktop to access other computers when not behind a firewall/proxy server.

As soon as I try to use Chrome Remote Desktop when behind a firewall/proxy server.  It can't connect.  Do certain ports/services need to be opened/enabled for it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome's support page suggests you need the ports for https (443) and xmpp/jabber (5222) open. It also suggests that if nat traversal is disallowed on the firewall, chrome remote won't work. There's also a few more troubleshooting suggestions on the [official google faq for chrome remote](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en) - the error messages might be informative, if you have any.